# lightdm and gdm not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, gdm

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04, the graphical mode can't started
in the log screen : `starting LightDM display manager [fail]` then I tried to use gdm, `starting gnome display manager fail`, i don't know how to fix this problem.

The problem now, when I try to install gdm or lightdm, I have the same error:

> /usr/bin/gdbus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_signal_accumulator_first_wins

Comment: Check out the for earlier problems, some issues with graphics drivers might have occurred and caused it to happen. The failure itself is does not tell much.

Comment: @Dugi i think that graphical card not correctly installed because ubuntu stuck at boot splash screen

Comment: In that case, you should specify what graphic card you have, what driver you have installed etc.

Comment: the problem now, when i try to install gdm or lightdm, i have the same error `/usr/bin/gdbus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_signal_accumulator_first_wins`

Comment: Edit the question to add this information. It's crucial.

Comment: Okay, now the problem is clear. But I have no idea what is causing that issue.